# Should Tailwind be listed under dependencies or devDependencies when developing a lbrary?

Tags: npm, dependencies, tailwind-css

I am building my first component library, which is based a lot on Tailwindcss. Would my clients need to have Tailwindcss installed? Because the code doesn't get compiled just yet when importing the components isn't it? It only gets compiled when building for production right?

But if it needs to be a dependency, what about all the configuration needed for Tailwind? Would me client need to do that as well? Or do my components get all the configuration they need from my code and retain all they need in my clients code? I'm talkin about `tailwind.config.js` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at creating your component library as a Tailwind plugin.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins

That is how Preline does it, https://preline.co/docs/index.html.

Therefore, to answer your questions, the users of your library would already need Tailwind installed and the code can then be compiled when building for production.

The Tailwind plugins documentation explains how to add new styles, variants, prefixes etc. You will need to follow this to add any custom configuration.